# How to create a simple Lync 2013 Presence 'Kiosk'?

Tags: lync, kiosk-mode, ucwa, user-presence

Basically, we're all pretty tired and rundown from a long stretch of constant-deployment and want to do something a little fun while the boss is away.

Downside, we're all SA's and Net Eng's and *not a developer amongst us*.

We are deploying **full on-premises installation of Lync 2013** (not a replacement, no 2010 infrastructure) to the masses in a couple of weeks, and as a "cool" bonus would like to have our very dated in/out slider board replaced with a large-screen Kiosk that shows the departments Lync status. We might add functionality later, but first - just a display of the current status is fine

We can install the client, any browser, plugins, anything we want - this is mostly just a proof of concept and a fun side project.

Most how-to dummy guides are for 2010, which don't seem to work.

In my head, it would be easiest to create a 'concierge' user, add the department to the contacts list, and then display the contact list on either a webpage, or a modified version of the client.

Any ideas where to start to hack this bad-boy together?  All connections would be internal, no need for external access.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up, what we discovered was the UCWA.

At first being intimidated by phrases like REST API etc, it was actually ridiculously easy to use.

Fired it up on a test IIS box, fiddled with some OAUTH and next thing we know, we had exactly what we were looking for and now I'm just waiting on a vendor to ship me a 34" Proof-of-concept touchscreen to play with.  :)

Thanks for the assistance all.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is indeed a simple an easy way to solve this. What you are looking for is the Lync client SDK for .Net:

- [Microsoft Lync 2013 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36824)

Assuming you have some version of Visual Studio running, you can then create a simple Windows Forms or WPF project and use the SDK to interact with the Lync Client as so:

- [How to: Display a contact list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933244.aspx)

This way you can easily show the contact list of your "Concierge" user.

Comment: This is exactly where I started with this, and surprisingly was able to get a contacts list running with Visual Studio 2012.  However, its 'prettiness' and functionality were quite difficult to tweak.

Answer (score 0):

Also, have a look at [UI Suppressed applications](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/08/the-6-things-you-need-to-know-about-ui-suppression-mode/) for full screen apps. You might also want to check out my [Desktop Development collection](http://www.thoughtstuff.co.uk/lync-desktop-development/) pages or [source code repro](http://code.thoughtstuff.co.uk). Good Luck! :)